# MySQL poor update performance with double inner join

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have 2 tables one is called `raw_data` which has 150m rows, the other one is called `income` which also has about 150m rows. I am trying to run the following query and it seems to get stuck after couple of hours. In `raw_data`, `MemberID` and `SiteID` have indexes, in `income`, `PersonID` and `SiteID` have indexes, both table's storage engine is MyISAM since we are using %99 select queries.

```
UPDATE `income` `t1` 
INNER JOIN `raw_data` `t2` 
   ON `t1`.`PersonID` = `t2`.`MemberID` AND `t1`.`SiteID` = `t2`.`SiteID` 
SET `t1`.`Age` = `t2`.`Age`, 
     `t1`.`Gender` = `t2`.`Gender`, 
     `t1`.`Sport` = `t2`.`Sport`, 
     `t1`.`PersonType` = `t2`.`PersonType`, 
     `t1`.`BookingType` = `t2`.`BookingType`, 
     `t1`.`TemplateName` = `t2`.`TemplateName`
```

Would you please help me to improve the performance and reduce the timing of this query?

Comment: Perhaps post the output of an EXPLAIN to help diagnose the poor performance?

Comment: +1 explain plan. Also what does that mean "being stuck"? Does the query completes at all? Does it updates partially or completely your data ?

Comment: It's not working at all, table is getting locked so cannot check the status. After couple of hours I am killing the query.

Comment: Tried explain, evenif I am using mysql 5.6, it gives syntax error when I add explain in front of the query.

Comment: "both table's storage engine is MyISAM since we are using %99 select queries" - this is not argument for using MyISAM. It used to be so, but since MySQL 5.3 InnoDB performs just as well or better than MyISAM for SELECTs.

Comment: Irrelevant response to be honest, I am just giving a brief about the table structure. I am not using innodb since the size doubles compare to myisam. Just asking, how to improve the performance of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*MyISAM* locks table until finished.

The query would run a lot faster with 'Composite' indexes (I'm not sure which one is preferred, may as well add both.):

```
income:    INDEX(PersonID, SiteID) -- in either order
raw_data:  INDEX(MemberID, SiteID) -- in either order
```

Note: *Separate* indexes on the two columns (which it sounds like you have) will *not* be as good.

You should also [*Switch to InnoDB*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/) .  99% Selects is not a sufficient excuse for using the antiquated, and soon to be removed, MyISAM.

Why copy data from one table to another?  Why not simply `JOIN` the two tables whenever you need it.  Or, phrased another way, "redundant data is a no-no".

[*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) is advice on 'chunking' an `UPDATE` to make it more civilized.

Comment: Thanks, will try what you suggested. Marking as resolved.